# Filesystem encryption settings during install?

Tags: centos, redhat, partition, encryption, software-raid

I'm installing CentOS 6.1 on a server and exploring the encryption settings in combination with software RAID.

- Should I encrypt the drive partition, the software RAID device, or
  both?
- Should I encrypt swap?

Wondering the pros/cons of each approach in case I mentally missed something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What sense should there be in encrypting both the md device and the underlying block device? It just slows things down.

Also, when using a RAID and encrypting the physical device, you would effectively encrypting the same set of data multiple times, again slowing things down.

As for encrypted Swap space: There can be intersting data in swapped out memory, but it depends on your threat model. If I would use encrypted disks, I would also encrypt swap space.

Comment: OK so should I encrypt the partition or the MD device?

Comment: @RobOlmos: Did you actually read my answer? If you encrypt the basic physical devices (possibly the partitions) of a software RAID, you will need to do the encryption multiple times, without any security benefit.